# HDD with many installation locations about to fail - can i move the software?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

recently one of my HDDs (Seagate 2TB hybrid SHDD, 4 partitions) produced checksum errors in utorrent*.

Tests yielded:

- ScanDisk (windows 10): No errors on all 4 partitions.
- chkdsk: No errors on all 4 partitions.
- SeaTool SMART test: passed.
- SeaTool Short Drive Self Test: Failed. Code: DF9EE6E7
- SeaTool  Short/Long generic: Passed.
- SeaTool Fix All - Fast: Failed. Code: DF9EE6E7

Code: DF9EE6E7 fails to produce google hits, so i have no idea what is going on.

The HDD itself is running smoothly, but i think i should go for an RMA of the disk producing the failures.

***The question is now how to best adjust windows to the soon-to-be-missing HDD.***

This HDD contains the partition for all installations i didn't want to use the OS-containing SSD.
In total, 59 apps are affected, including office, dropbox folders, origin, steam, and so on.

*- Is there a way to mass-move all installed programs to another hdd (i happen to have a 2nd seagate)?*

*- How would you deal with this?*

*- Can i try to copy/mirror the partitions and copy it later to the replacement hdd?*

*- Will windows notice it, e.g. when partitions are not exactly the same size?
In this case, i should uninstall all 59 apps, rather than installing them onto the replacement hdd?*

I have never done anything like this before.
Any help is appreciated.

*i thought it would be approbiate to stress that i dont use utorrent for illegal activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [disk imaging program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_cloning_software) (e.g. macrium reflect; acronis; clonezilla) will do what you want, and "no" probably the OS nor installed software will not notice or care, so long as the partition drive letters are the same.

If you do not have Windows OS files on the partitions you probably can get away with building 4 partitions and then using [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) to mirror the files (with the /MIR option). Again, if you keep the same drive assignments, any software that stores or tracks that upon install will *most likely* not care or notice. You will want to check carefully for any in-use or locked files in the Robocopy log, and you want to ensure the directory tree structure is identical on the destination partiton(s).

Obviously the destination partitions will need temporary drive letter assignments, but you can label the volumes to keep track of them and then re-assign drive letters after you unplug the source drive.

I tend to like to use imaging software for the OS/bootable drive because I want it to be bootable and with minimum hassle but I would probably simply run a robocopy process to transfer between "strictly data" drives.

EDIT:

`robocopy F:\ H:\ /mir /R:2 /W:2 /TEE /LOG:"%userprofile%\desktop\robocopy_log.txt" /L`

`/L` is list only, this is to test the copy process to ensure your commands are what you meant. Remove `/L` to run it for real.

`/R` and `/W` are retries (per file) and how many seconds to wait between retries

`/LOG:` is to log to a file, overwriting the file. Check the log for skipped or in-use files.

`/TEE` is output to console as well as file

`/MIR` will mirror to destination, note that **it will delete files in the destination that are not present in the source**

You can cancel the process and start over and it will skip files that have already been copied (and have not changed since then).

Remember to save the original drive for some arbitrary period of time until you are confident the process worked and everything is happy.

Comment: thank you. what i dont really understand is the purging effect of /mir, because my destination partition is empty, so no files could be deleted. Or where do i mess up?